# How do I extract name from path and add them as names of elements of list inside lapply

Tags: r, lapply

How do I extract name from path and add them as names of elements of list inside lapply.

I want the name of the elements in the `tbl_list` to be [["Employees"]] and [["Performances"]] i.e. extract name of the csv_files after last _ till before .csv.

```
library(tidyverse)

# list of path of files
csv_files <- c("C:/Dropbox (UFL)/Projects/Datasets/Company_A_-_Employees.csv",
               "C:/Dropbox (UFL)/Projects/Datasets/Company_A_-_Performances.csv")


# read all files using lapply
tbl_list <- lapply(X = csv_files, FUN = read_csv)


tbl_list has two elements [[1]] and [[2]] corresponding to each csv_files.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names(tbl_list) <- gsub(".*_(.*)\\.csv$", "\\1", csv_files)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there is a way to do it inside lapply and does that have any advantage

Comment: not that I am aware of.